# PHP opauth facebook

Tags: php, facebook, slim, oauth2

Estou fazendo atenticação com o facebook usando opauth.org
framework slim3.

O não estou recebendo o sexo.

Recebo os outros dados: [teste site](https://app.pegadadelixo.com.br/auth)

Alguem sabe se tem um erro de sintaxe?

```
$gender = @$auth['raw']['gender'];
```

O código completo:

```
    switch(strtolower($auth['provider'])) {
    case 'facebook' :
        $oauth_id = $auth['uid'];
        $password = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);
        $info = $auth['info'];
        $firstname = @explode(' ', @$info['name'])[0];
        $lastname = @explode(' ', @$info['name'])[1];
        $image = @$info['image'];
        $gender = @$auth['raw']['gender'];
        $credentials = serialize(@$auth['credentials']);
        if (!empty ($username = $info['email'])) $this-> $username = @$info['email'];

        else  {
        $username = $oauth_id;

        }
```